# How to reassign default editor for different file types from the command line?

Tags: text-editor

I am looking for a way to reassign default editor on OS X. For example I want to reassign all file types opened by TextEditor with TextWrangler.

Probably it has something to do with the `defaults` command but I do not know how to list current assignments and change them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a command line utility called Duti which can do this.

http://duti.sourceforge.net/

There is no easy way to do this using built-in commands.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [this question on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/20822/where-does-mac-os-x-store-file-association-information). It's not really as easy as editing `.plist` file with `defaults`.